# How to produce random symmetric matrix given the number of vertices?

Tags: matlab, matrix, random, transpose

Is there a simple way to produce a random matrix of 0's and 1's, that is symmetric across the diagonal (with only zeros in the diagonal), given the number of vertices?

**Example:**

```
somefunction(3) =  [ 0 1 1; 
                     1 0 0; 
                     1 0 0]; 

somefunction(4) = [ 0 1 1 1; 
                    1 0 0 1; 
                    1 0 0 1; 
                    1 1 1 0];
```

Comment: The first one isn't symmetric.

Comment: My mistake. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You can generate a random matrix and extract lower triangular part of it then do `OR` with its transpose:

```
n = 4;
a=tril(randi(0:1,n),-1);
result = a|a.';
```